# p4 - how to edit a file that's opened for add or not in client

Tags: version-control, perforce

I am new to p4, so some explanations will be much appreciated and more helpful than the answer itself.

I want to edit a file foo.txt. I am in the directory where this file lives.

My attempts to edit foo.txt have been the following:

```
$p4 sync
File(s) up-to-date.

$p4 edit foo.txt
foo.txt - files(s) not on client

$p4 add foo.txt
//depot/directory/foo.txt#1 - opened for add
$p4 edit foo.txt
//depot/directory/foo.txt#1 - can't edit (already opened for add)
```

The fact that there isn't much info on this when Googling this issue indicates that it's probably trivial.

Comment: Thank you, MuertoExcobito. That fixed me. Also thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If a file does not exist in perforce, you cannot edit it. If a file is currently opened for add, you don't need to edit it. When you submit the change that contains the add, the contents of the file at that time are used. Once you have submitted the change adding the file, any time you want to subsequently modify the file, you would do `p4 edit foo.txt` to add it to a changelist, make changes, and then submit that change.

Comment: I offence [not to @MuertoExcobito but to perforce :) ] on "If a file is currently opened for add, you don't need to edit it". I'm editing a file which newly added, but before submitting..... but it is readonly. I dont want to submit it without a change. What to do?

Comment: @chandpriyankara - If a file is opened for add in perforce, you can continue to modify it before submitting it. Perforce doesn't  set files opened for add as readonly, it likely got set some other way. So... simply use `chmod +w`/`attrib -r` to unset the readonly flag on the file.